# Jquery Mobile navbar binding results in multiple click events and random behavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navbar

Using Jquery Mobile 1.0b

```
<div class="navSubBars" id="cat0Nav" data-role="navbar" style=" padding-top: 2px;">
  <ul>
    <li>item1
    <li>item2
    <li>item3
    <li>item4
 </ul>
</div>

$('.navSubBars>ul>li>a').live('vclick',function() {
  var subMenuItem = $(this).text();
  alert(subMenuItem);
});
```

First click event fires an alert. click any other item (anchor) on the page and another click event immediately fires. Subsequent clicks intermittently fires correctly, some don't fire an alert at all. Very random.

I need this to load dynamic content in a div on the same page, in case that helps.

I have tried chaining an unbind to bind, stopping propagation and return false, and different selectors, all with no success.

I'm looking for a work around, fix, or better approach.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You li tags are not valid HTML.

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/qedNv/

HTML: (adding a class attribute to access each li)

```
<div data-role="page" id="jqm-home" class="type-home"> 
    <div data-role="content">        
        <div class="navSubBars" id="cat0Nav" data-role="navbar" style=" padding-top: 2px;">
            <ul>
                <li class="click-li">item1</li>
                <li class="click-li">item2</li>
                <li class="click-li">item3</li>
                <li class="click-li">item4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.click-li').live('vclick', function() {
   var subMenuItem = $(this).text();
    alert('Sub Menu Item: '+subMenuItem);
});
```